# how to format string in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

In the database column1 have date like 2011-03-03 but I want to show only 03-03 and in
 column2 have string like BHEL.NS but I want to show only BHEL.

```
<TD><center><%=rs.getString(1)%></center></TD>  
<TD><center><%=rs.getString(2)%></center></TD>
```

How to do this?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TD><center><%=rs.getString(1)!=null?rs.getString(1).subString(rs.getString(1).indexOf("-")+1):"-"%></center></TD>  
<TD><center><%=rs.getString(2)!=null?rs.getString(2).subString(0,rs.getString(2).indexOf(".")):"-"%></center></TD>
```

Answer (score 2):

For date you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) and for second column use [substring function of String](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29).

Or use substring for both as

```
rs.getString(1).substring(rs.getString(1).indexOf("-")+1)  
rs.getString(2).substring(0,rs.getString(2).indexOf("."))
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to [avoid javacode in view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) You can have List of your POJOs fetched and filled up from DB , and then you can render it on view using JSTL

And with your current way you can make it working by following way

```
<TD><center><%=rs.getString(1).subString(rs.getString(1).indexOf("-")+1)%></center></TD>  
<TD><center><%=rs.getString(2).subString(0,rs.getString(2).indexOf("."))%></center></TD>
```

**Also See**

- [JSP Coding convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/code-convention-138726.html)

Comment: It should be `<%=rs.getString(2).subString(0,rs.getString(2).indexOf("."))%>` for second column.

Comment: Yeah typo. <!---------------------->